# Pandas column disappears after using bfill

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe using a set of columns from a much larger dataframe

I have used the bfill function to fill up missing date values in certain columns.However in a classic scenario, one of these columns come with only null values and after bfill, that column disappears

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import shutil
import xlrd
import xlwt
import glob
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import os
from pandas import ExcelWriter

for f in glob.glob("Raw/*.xlsx"):
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    df1 = xls.parse(sheet_name=0)
    #print(df1.shape)
    new = df1.filter(['Actual Start',
                      'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Issued for Self Discipline Check (SDC)(Actual Finish Date)',
                      'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Issued for Inter-disciplinary Check  (IDC)(Actual Finish Date)',
                      'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Submission to client(Actual Finish Date)',
                      'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Reviewed by Client(Actual Finish Date)',
                      'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Approved by Client (FAC)(Actual Finish Date)',
                      'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Issue for Construction(Actual Finish Date)',
                      'FOR PR with offer Evaluation-Discipline Completed (SDC)(Actual Finish Date)',
                      'FOR PR with offer Evaluation-Issuance to procurement team (FRB)(Actual Finish Date)','FOR PR with offer Evaluation-Tech. Evaluation Completion(Actual Finish Date)'], axis=1)
    #print(new.shape)
    
    cols = new.columns
    new[cols] = new[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime).bfill(axis=1)
    print(cols)
```

OUTPUT:
The column : FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Approved by Client (FAC)(Actual Finish Date) is no longer in the dataframe

```
Index(['Actual Start',
       'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Issued for Self Discipline Check (SDC)(Actual Finish Date)',
       'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Issued for Inter-disciplinary Check  (IDC)(Actual Finish Date)',
       'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Submission to client(Actual Finish Date)',
       'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Reviewed by Client(Actual Finish Date)',
       'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Issue for Construction(Actual Finish Date)',
       'FOR PR with offer Evaluation-Discipline Completed (SDC)(Actual Finish Date)',
       'FOR PR with offer Evaluation-Issuance to procurement team (FRB)(Actual Finish Date)',
       'FOR PR with offer Evaluation-Tech. Evaluation Completion(Actual Finish Date)'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to see a problem directly related to `bfill`. It's a bit difficult to understand the problem entirely without sample data. But the way you select columns is non-idiomatic. Does the following work for you?

```py
# Columns of interest
cols = ['Actual Start',
        'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Issued for Self Discipline Check (SDC)(Actual Finish Date)',
        'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Issued for Inter-disciplinary Check  (IDC)(Actual Finish Date)',
        'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Submission to client(Actual Finish Date)',
        'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Reviewed by Client(Actual Finish Date)',
        'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Approved by Client (FAC)(Actual Finish Date)',
        'FOR CLIENT SUBMISSION / APPROVAL-Issue for Construction(Actual Finish Date)',
        'FOR PR with offer Evaluation-Discipline Completed (SDC)(Actual Finish Date)',
        'FOR PR with offer Evaluation-Issuance to procurement team (FRB)(Actual Finish Date)','FOR PR with offer Evaluation-Tech. Evaluation Completion(Actual Finish Date)']

for f in glob.glob("Raw/*.xlsx"):
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    df1 = xls.parse(sheet_name=0)
    # Select the columns of interest
    new1 = df1[cols]
    new2 = new1.apply(pd.to_datetime)
    new3 = new2.bfill(axis=0)
```

**Update:** [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) means backward-fill, it fills nan-gaps by using the next valid observation along the axis. If you want to fill nan's along the column axis, you should call `df.bfill(axis=0)`. (I believe that the `axis=1` in your code was not what you intended) Note that an empty column (with just nan values) will remain empty after `bfill`. It is in no way possible that `bfill` removes a column.

Comment: nope it does not, I think if a column is entirely full of NULLs then bfill is facing a challenge in putting the values

Comment: No, `bfill` is capable of handling entirely empty columns. Try it out. Note that `bfill` for an empty column results in an empty column. But the column cannot disappear from the data frame just by calling `bfill`.

Comment: @MKD I slightly edited my code. Can you report which line results in an unexpected output? (new1, new2, new3)

Comment: i have found the solution there was an extra space here : Client (FAC) in my code. the excel data used as input earlier had this space and the code ran just fine, however in the new dataset there is no spaces, can you suggest a way how i can handle such scenarios ?

Comment: @MKD I think you need [`df = df.rename(lookup, axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html). Lookup is a dict with (old,new) key-value pairs.